# PyQt: Qtreeview how to implement a different header for child and parent?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtreeview

I would like to implement a simple qtreeview which has a different header for parent and children, depending on which one is selected. For example :

- parent1   parentAttr1   ParentAttr2 ...

  - child1    childAttr1   childAttr2 ...
  - child2   childAttr1   childAttr2 ...
- parent2   parentAttr1   ParentAttr2 ...

then if I select a parent row, I will see a parent header and conversely with the child row.

Can anyone give me a simple working example ?

Comment: Seems no easy way. The only solution I can came up with is changing the header whenever currentItem change.

Comment: You'd be much more likely to get an answer, if you included code which produces the tree view, but with static header. Also, generally speaking, asking others to just write code for you si generally received poorly (meaning down votes and close votes), and showing your existing code is easiest way to placate the crowds in this respect.